# Spring Kotlin - Changed object to class and got error

Tags: spring, kotlin

I changed my code from this:

```
object SomeHelper{}
```

to this:

```
@Component 
class SomeHelper(private val anAttribute: AnAttributeService){}
```

`AnAttributeService` looks like this:

```
@Service
class AnAttributeService(private val myLoader: MyLoader){}
```

This is `MyLoader`:

```
interface MyLoader {
  fun loadSomething()
}
```

In my test class I wrote something like this:

```
class SomeHelperTester{
val cut = SomeHelper
//...
}
```

which used to work fine when SomeHelper was an object, but now when I write

```
val cut = SomeHelper(anAttribute = AnAttributeService(myLoader = MyLoader))
```

MyLoader is red underlined with an error saying `Classifier MyLoader does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized`

How can I make this line of code work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Kotlin - Changed object to class and got error saying "classifier does not have a companion object and thus must be initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69811255/spring-kotlin-changed-object-to-class-and-got-error-saying-classifier-does-no)

Answer (score 2):

after the `myLoader =` you need to provide an instance of type `MyLoader`. you can't just say `MyLoader` there.

If `MyLoader` was a class you could have just changed it to `MyLoader()`. But you defined `MyLoader` as an interface, which means you need to provide an implementation for it.

The most common way to do it is to make a class that extends the interface and create an instance of that. for example:

```
class MyLoaderImp: MyLoader {
    override fun loadSomething() {
        //implementation here
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
val cut = SomeHelper(anAttribute = AnAttributeService(myLoader = MyLoaderImp()))
```

also note, in kotlin you don't need to mention the parameter names explicitly unless you provide them in another order or are leaving out some, so this is also valid and shorter

```
val cut = SomeHelper(AnAttributeService(MyLoaderImp()))
```

alternatively you can provide an implementation in an anonymous class like this

```
val cut = SomeHelper(AnAttributeService(object: MyLoader{
    override fun loadSomething() {
        //implementation here
    }
}))
```

It seems to me that you still lack a lot of the basics about kotlin and programming in general. I suggest you to study some sections of the documentation on kotlin's website to get a better understanding of everything:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html